# build an email database with pywin32

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, office-automation

I have to iterate through many shared folders within my company. I need to store all the strings of the messages in a database for a machine learning project.
I read in some threads that I should not iterate through all items using pywin32 and

```
messages = mapi.Folders(str(key)).Folders(str(i)).Items
```

We are talking about 10 shared inboxes with each over 10.000 mails. When i tried to run my code for the first inbox it crashed after reaching 95% (according to tqdm) with this error code

> File
> ~.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356
> in compat_exec
> exec(code, globals, locals)
>
> File c:\users\user\desktop\untitled0.py:206 in 
> for m in tqdm(messages):
>
> File ~.conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py:1195 in
> **iter**
> for obj in iterable:
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py:324
> in **getitem**
> return self.*get_good_object*(self.*enum*.**getitem**(index))
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py:41
> in **getitem**
> return self.__GetIndex(index)
>
> File
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py:62
> in __GetIndex
> result = self.*oleobj*.Next(1)
>
> com_error: (-459013867, 'OLE error 0xe4a40115', None, None)

I don't understand this error and i can't find anything googling this error. So i thought I should just slice them just in smaller parts and run the code. But I can't slice the messages as I get the error code

```
TypeError: Objects of type 'slice' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT
```

Is there any other way or even a more efficient way to do this task? Should I use instead of pywin32 any other libary? It seems like this is the most proficient libary in this field as it is from microsoft and should have the best compatibility with outlook. But going through 48000 emails of 50000 and then seeing this crash was not planned. How could I save my progress on the way? Can I just sort the messages first and then iterate and therefore commit my retrieved data to an sql database every 5000 emails?

Comment: Which line of your code raises that error?

Answer (score 0):

You must release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. This number was increased in latest Exchange versions, but the strategy remains valid. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. You can read more about Exchange limits in the [Managed Store Limits in Exchange Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/mailbox-servers/managed-store/managed-store-limits?view=exchserver-2019) article.

I'd recommend processing items in bunch, for example, scope them to a day or week, to be able to avoid limits introduced by the Exchange server. The `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class can help you with such tasks. You can read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Be aware, a low-level API on which Outlook is based on allows running secondary threads, so you could run your stuff on a secondary thread leaving the Outlook UI responsive. If the API is too complex for you, consider using any wrappers around that API such as Redemption.